# Setup .env file by CI4 controller

Tags: codeigniter, environment-variables, environment, codeigniter-4

im new in CI4 i would like to create setup database by CI4 it is possible write db connection data to .env file by controller or some services CI4? 
Also want when complete setup change environment in .env that user cant access setup.
If its not correct solution can some one tell how to do it best way?

im using CI 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In app/Config/Database.php you can set up multiple possible databases and from there you can depend them on specific environment.

By default you have 2 set up databases - default and tests. If env is set to tests it will load tests database settings, else will load default. You can expand it by adding more possible environments.

As in env file, there is section DATABASE, you can edit them there.

Comment: this i know but i want to create setup environment, for example user unpack CI4 start setup page firstly complete setup all writen data by user writes to env file or database.php file as default and then on finish change environment from setup to production to show pages and for security user cant turn on simply setup